# problem with localStorage and JSON.parse, error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1430

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have a problem with JSON.stringify, I'll explain.

I receive from an ajax call the following JSON:
[image]

Whenever I receive a similar JSON, I want to do a JSON.stringify (result.responseJSON.eventsTRS) that I add in a variable declared at the top of my JS file "var eventsJSON = ''".

Once the JSON.stringify is done, this is what I get:
[image]

then I do a localStorage.setItem ('eventsJSON', eventsJSON) and I get:
[image]

Then with my getItem I do a JSON.parse (localStorage.getItem ('eventsJSON')).
Out, when I do my parse, I have the following error message:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [in JSON at position 1430

Why would you be?

Regards,

Comment: can you show position 1430 in the string?

Comment: I didn't actually think about looking precisely at the content of my JSON.

I have 3 JSON arrays in it, because in my javascript code, I loop over dates (and for 3 dates there is JSON).

For each loop round, I do eventsJSON + = JSON.stringify (result.responseJSON.eventsTRS).
eventsJSON being declared earlier in the code (var eventsJSON = '').

What I would need is to fill the same JSON object every time I loop it, not add a new JSON object.

I don't see how I can do it.
Do you have an idea ?

thank you,
Regards,

Comment: The error means that the string is malformed.  Unless you show us what is at position 1430, plus parts before and after than so we have context, no one can say what the issue is precisely.  So, if you want an answer, you have to show what is causing the problem.

Comment: OK - from that new code - which really should have been updated into your Question not as an Answer, I can see that the issue is that the string contains `][` twice.  There are, therefore, three arrays.  You will need to replace these with `,` before using JSON.parse so that you end up with just one array

Comment: I have just testing this manually by replacing `][` with `,` and the data now loads entirely as one array.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry,

this is my code :

```
                    for(var i=start ; i<=end;i++ ){
                  $.ajax({
                      dataType: "json",
                      url: "urlServlet",
                      async: false,
                      data: {
                          date: i,
                          action: 'rendementsJourTRS'
                      },
                      sucess: function(data){
                          
                      }, error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
                          console.log(erreur);
                       }, complete : function(resultat, statut){
                           if(undefined!=resultat.responseJSON.eventsTRS && ''!=resultat.responseJSON.eventsTRS){
                               eventsJSON += JSON.stringify(resultat.responseJSON.eventsTRS);   

                               //Utilisation
                               localStorage.setItem('eventsJSON', eventsJSON);
                           }
                           
                          
                           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', resultat.responseJSON.eventsTRS);
                           
                       }
                  });
            }
```

For each day, I add a JSON of the day in eventsJSON.

This is my localStorage.getItem('eventsJSON') contents :

```
"[{"resourceId":"0117-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":50},{"resourceId":"0302-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-03","title":90},{"resourceId":"0308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-03","title":83},{"resourceId":"1801-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1804-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2930-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":0},{"resourceId":"6601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-03","title":68},{"resourceId":"6602-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-03","title":60},{"resourceId":"6603-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-03","title":68},{"resourceId":"6605-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6608-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":55},{"resourceId":"6609-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":34},{"resourceId":"7304-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"7308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":2}][{"resourceId":"2117-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":72},{"resourceId":"2118-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":75},{"resourceId":"6601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":77},{"resourceId":"6602-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-04","title":59},{"resourceId":"6603-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-04","title":60},{"resourceId":"6605-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-04","title":21},{"resourceId":"6608-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-04","title":14},{"resourceId":"6609-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":75}][{"resourceId":"0102-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":87},{"resourceId":"0104-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":91},{"resourceId":"0124-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"0201-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":94},{"resourceId":"0203-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":90},{"resourceId":"0205-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":70},{"resourceId":"0206-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":87},{"resourceId":"0207-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":85},{"resourceId":"0218-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":99},{"resourceId":"0302-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":70},{"resourceId":"0308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":86},{"resourceId":"0910-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":73},{"resourceId":"0911-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":93},{"resourceId":"1212-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":87},{"resourceId":"1215-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1216-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":95},{"resourceId":"1219-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":91},{"resourceId":"1222-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":98},{"resourceId":"1801-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1802-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":51},{"resourceId":"1803-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1804-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2002-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2401-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":97},{"resourceId":"2402-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":95},{"resourceId":"2701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2704-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"9701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":82},{"resourceId":"1918-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":84},{"resourceId":"1919-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2117-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":88},{"resourceId":"2220-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":0},{"resourceId":"2221-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":70},{"resourceId":"2324-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2929-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":0},{"resourceId":"3201-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":82},{"resourceId":"3202-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":88},{"resourceId":"3401-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":69},{"resourceId":"3402-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3403-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":91},{"resourceId":"3601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3604-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":69},{"resourceId":"3015-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3016-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6103-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":62},{"resourceId":"6107-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":47},{"resourceId":"6601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":2},{"resourceId":"6602-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":61},{"resourceId":"6603-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6605-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6608-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":43},{"resourceId":"6609-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":88},{"resourceId":"7308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":95},{"resourceId":"7409-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":77},{"resourceId":"7410-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":85}]"
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the string actually contains three array, not one.  There are two points in the string (1430 being the first), where there is `][` instead of `,`  Replacing these turns the three arrays into one, which loads as a full array correctly.  Thus:

```
...."title":2}][{"resourceId":"2117....
```

should be:

```
...."title":2},{"resourceId":"2117....
```

```js
let s = '[{"resourceId":"0117-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":50},{"resourceId":"0302-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-03","title":90},{"resourceId":"0308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-03","title":83},{"resourceId":"1801-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1804-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2930-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":0},{"resourceId":"6601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-03","title":68},{"resourceId":"6602-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-03","title":60},{"resourceId":"6603-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-03","title":68},{"resourceId":"6605-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6608-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":55},{"resourceId":"6609-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":34},{"resourceId":"7304-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-03","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"7308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-03","title":2}][{"resourceId":"2117-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":72},{"resourceId":"2118-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":75},{"resourceId":"6601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":77},{"resourceId":"6602-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-04","title":59},{"resourceId":"6603-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-04","title":60},{"resourceId":"6605-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-04","title":21},{"resourceId":"6608-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-04","title":14},{"resourceId":"6609-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-04","title":75}][{"resourceId":"0102-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":87},{"resourceId":"0104-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":91},{"resourceId":"0124-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"0201-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":94},{"resourceId":"0203-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":90},{"resourceId":"0205-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":70},{"resourceId":"0206-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":87},{"resourceId":"0207-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":85},{"resourceId":"0218-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":99},{"resourceId":"0302-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":70},{"resourceId":"0308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":86},{"resourceId":"0910-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":73},{"resourceId":"0911-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":93},{"resourceId":"1212-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":87},{"resourceId":"1215-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1216-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":95},{"resourceId":"1219-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":91},{"resourceId":"1222-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":98},{"resourceId":"1801-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1802-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":51},{"resourceId":"1803-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"1804-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2002-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2401-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":97},{"resourceId":"2402-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":95},{"resourceId":"2701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2704-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"9701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":82},{"resourceId":"1918-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":84},{"resourceId":"1919-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2117-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":88},{"resourceId":"2220-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":0},{"resourceId":"2221-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":70},{"resourceId":"2324-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"2929-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":0},{"resourceId":"3201-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":82},{"resourceId":"3202-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":88},{"resourceId":"3401-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":69},{"resourceId":"3402-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3403-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":91},{"resourceId":"3601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3604-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3701-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":69},{"resourceId":"3015-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"3016-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6103-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":62},{"resourceId":"6107-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":47},{"resourceId":"6601-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":2},{"resourceId":"6602-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(255, 179, 0)","start":"2020-10-05","title":61},{"resourceId":"6603-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6605-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(58, 68, 78)","start":"2020-10-05","title":"++"},{"resourceId":"6608-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(244, 67, 54)","start":"2020-10-05","title":43},{"resourceId":"6609-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":88},{"resourceId":"7308-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":95},{"resourceId":"7409-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(246, 220, 18)","start":"2020-10-05","title":77},{"resourceId":"7410-trs","backgroundColor":"rgb(139, 195, 74)","start":"2020-10-05","title":85}]';

let newS = s.replace(/(\]\[)/gm, ",");

let jsonS = JSON.parse(newS);

console.log(jsonS);
```